# How to correctly use OmniFaces in an EAR

Tags: jsf-2, ear, omnifaces, skinny-war

I want to use [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) 1.7 in my Jave EE 7 application. My application is an EAR that contains JARs and a [skinny WAR](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/skinny-wars.html). Some of my JARs have a dependency to OmniFaces, so the OmniFaces artifact must be in the EAR but not in `WEB-INF/lib` in the WAR.

Here is how my EAR looks like:

```
EAR
 +-- lib
 |    +-- [some 3rd party JARs]
 |    `-- omnifaces.jar
 +-- myEJBs.jar
 `-- myWAR.war
```

When I put it this way, OmniFaces converters (like [`GenericEnumConverter`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/GenericEnumConverter)) are not registered with JSF and won't work. The reason for this is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907290/omnifaces-ear-deployment-issue-on-glassfish-3-1-2-2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987266/why-doesnt-jsf-2-0-ri-mojarra-scan-my-class-annotations). Basically according to the [JSF 2.0 Spec](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=314) (section *11.5.1 Requirements for scanning of classes for annotations*), only the WARs `WEB-INF/lib` directory is scanned.

So my question is: **how should I include OmniFaces in my application**?

Including it twice (in `EAR/lib` and WARs `WEB-INF/lib`) could possibly work but feels clumsy. I tried it some time ago with RichFaces 4.3.5 (same problem) which didn't work but led to `IllegalArgumentException: duplicate key: class javax.faces.convert.ByteConverter`.

Comment: At [OmniFaces' known issues page](https://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/wiki/KnownIssuesCDI) is stated: "Also noted should be that OmniFaces can simply not be included as an EAR library due to dependencies which are typically only available inside the WAR, like JSF, Servlet and EL." But what if I want to use classes like `org.omnifaces.config.BeanManager` in my EJBs?

Comment: After a [discussion](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Are-skinny-WARs-still-recommended-td5786626.html) on the maven-users list I think OmniFaces' classes like BeanManager or Utils should currently not be used from classes outside the WAR. A solution could be to split OmniFaces in two separate JARs: a true JSF Component Library and a common library usable everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OmniFaces is a JSF utility library with dependencies on JSF, EL and Servlet APIs, which are normally only available inside a WAR, not an EAR. Even more, your EJBs (business services in general) are not supposed to have any dependencies on specific front-end APIs such as JSF, EL and Servlet APIs. It would make them unreusable on other front-ends such as JAX-RS, Spring MVC, etc.

You need to put JSF utility and component libraries such as OmniFaces and PrimeFaces in WAR, not in EAR. See also [Installation](http://omnifaces.org/#installation) section of OmniFaces homepage:

> OmniFaces is designed as a WAR library (web fragment library) and therefore can't be placed elsewhere in the webapp's runtime classpath outside WAR's own `/WEB-INF/lib`, such as EAR's `/lib` or even server's or JRE's own `/lib`. When OmniFaces JAR file is misplaced this way, then the webapp will be unable to find OmniFaces-bundled JSF/CDI annotated classes and throw exceptions related to this during deploy or runtime. To solve it, put back OmniFaces in WAR's `/WEB-INF/lib`.

#### See also:

- [JSF Service Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011392/jsf-service-layer/)
- [@FacesComponent on shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535024/facescomponent-on-shared-library/)
- [@Eager is unavailable. The EagerBeansRepository could not be obtained from CDI bean manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549560/eager-is-unavailable-the-eagerbeansrepository-could-not-be-obtained-from-cdi-b/)

Comment: Just for the records: I only had a dependency to OmniFaces' `BeanManager` class (as discussed on the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/issues/detail?id=313)). And using CDI in EJBs is a valid use-case. But I ended up with the solution you suggested to put OmniFaces in the WAR. Thx.