# @FacesComponent on shared library

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, websphere, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to use a custom jsf component on Websphere 8.5.
The component class is annotated with @FacesComponent.

The component is on a shared lib jar on the server. I already have an faces-config inside the jar META-INF folder.

If the jar is inside my ear file it works as expected, but when its 
on a sharedlib it gives me "Undefined component type MyUIActionList" error.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: What do you mean "when it's on a sharedlib"? What's a "sharedlib"?

Comment: @davids: in a folder that is on a server wide classpath. Usable for each applicication that is deployed

Comment: Did you created shared library via Environment > Shared libraries, or put the jar somewhere else? (what you mean by server wide classpath??)

Comment: @Gas i did it, but the reason it was not working what BalusC explained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web fragment JARs belong in `WAR/WEB-INF/lib` and **absolutely not** in `EAR/lib` nor `Server/lib`.

See also a.o. chapter 8.1 of [Servlet 3.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-oth-JSpec/) (emphasis mine):

> ## 8.1 Annotations and pluggability
>
> In a web application, classes using annotations will have their annotations processed
>   **only** if they are located in the `WEB-INF/classes` directory, or if they are packaged
>   in a jar file located in `WEB-INF/lib` within the application.
>
> ...

End of story.