# Managed Bean annotation not working

Tags: jsf-2, managed-bean

**Version** :

RichFaces 4.3.5

Apache MyFaces 2.1

Tomcat 6

**Issue** :

We are using JSF2 . 
I am not able to invoke a managed bean action method using annotation.

Below is the code for managed bean.

```
@ManagedBean(name="controller")
@RequestScoped
public class Controller {

    public String getUserName(){

    }

}
```

The bean has been invoked like below :

sample.xhtml :

```
#{controller.userName}
```

I have checked that all the `faces-config.xml` in my web application adhere to JSF2 namespace.

I am using tomcat 6 to deploy the web application.

When same bean is added in `faces-config.xml`,the bean method gets executed successfully.

Is there anything else I need to take care for this to work ? 
Please help .

Comment: Is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987266/why-doesnt-jsf-2-0-ri-mojarra-scan-my-class-annotations

Comment: What package are you importing the annotations from?

Comment: @kolossus - +1 your comment helped me; IDE had imported `javax.annotations.ManagedBean` by default instead of `javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean`

Comment: @kolossus you might want to provide your tip as a answer to close this question.